# Converting All Redundant Floats in a String to Integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I'm using Sympy to make a custom function which converts complex square roots into their complex numbers. When I input `-sqrt(-2 + 2*sqrt(3)*I)` I get the expected output of `-1 - sqrt(3)*I`, however, inputting `-sqrt(-2.0 + 2*sqrt(3)*I)` (has a `-2.0` instead of `-2`), I get the output `-1.0 - 0.707106781186547*sqrt(6)*I`.

I've tried to convert the input expression to a string, gotten rid of the `'.0 '` and then executed a piece of code to return it to the type `sympy.core.add.Mul`, which usually works with other strings, but the variable `expression` is still a string.

```
expression = str(input_expression).replace('.0 ', '')
exec(f'expression = {expression}')
```

How do I get rid of the redundant use of floats in my expression, while maintaining its type of `sympy.core.add.Mul`, so that my function will give a nice output?

*P.S.* The number `0.707106781186547` is an approximation of `1/sqrt(2)`. The fact that this number is present in the second output means that my function is running properly, it just isn't outputting in the desired way.

**Edit:**
For whatever reason, unindenting and getting rid of the function as a whole, running the code as its own program gives the expected output. It's only when the code is in function form that it doesn't work.

**Code as Requested:**

```
from IPython.display import display, Math
from sympy.abc import *
from sympy import *

def imaginary_square_root(x, y):
    return(sqrt((x + sqrt(x**2 + y**2)) / (2)) + I*((y*sqrt(2)) / (2*sqrt(x + sqrt(x**2 + y**2))))) # calculates the square root of a complex number

def find_imaginary_square_root(polynomial): # 'polynomial' used because this function is meant to change expressions including variables such as 'x'
    polynomial = str(polynomial).replace('.0 ', ' ')
    exec(f'polynomial = {polynomial}')

    list_of_square_roots = [] # list of string instances of square roots and their contents
    list_of_square_root_indexes = [] # list of indexes at which the square roots can be found in the string
    polynomial_string = str(polynomial)
    temp_polynomial_string = polynomial_string # string used and chopped up, hence the prefix 'temp_...'
    current_count = 0 # counter variable used for two seperate jobs

    while 'sqrt' in temp_polynomial_string: # gets indexes of every instance of 'sqrt'
        list_of_square_root_indexes.append(temp_polynomial_string.index('sqrt') + current_count)
        temp_polynomial_string = temp_polynomial_string[list_of_square_root_indexes[-1] + 4:]
        current_count += list_of_square_root_indexes[-1] + 4

    for square_root_location in list_of_square_root_indexes:
        current_count = 1 # second job for 'current_count'

        for index, char in enumerate(polynomial_string[square_root_location + 5:]):
            if char == '(':
                current_count += 1

            elif char == ')':
                current_count -= 1

            if not current_count: # when current_count == 0, we know that the end of the sqrt contents have been reached
                list_of_square_roots.append(polynomial_string[square_root_location:square_root_location + index + 6]) # adds the square root with contents to a list
                break

    for individual_square_root in list_of_square_roots:
        if individual_square_root in str(polynomial):
            evaluate = individual_square_root[5:-1]
            x = re(evaluate)
            y = im(evaluate)

            polynomial = polynomial.replace(eval(individual_square_root), imaginary_square_root(x, y)) # replace function used here is Sympy's replace function for polynomials

    return polynomial

poly = str(-sqrt(-2.0 + 2*sqrt(3)*I))

display(Math(latex(find_imaginary_square_root(poly))))
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide us with the chunk of code and the function so that we can potentially see what the problem was? Also, I'm not sure if the replace method you're using is going to behave as you'd expect. What would happen if the input was given as `sqrt(1.02 + 1.06*I)`? I'd also check out sympy's [string parsing functionality](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html), it help accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JoeHabel This function is meant to be a smaller section of a larger algorithm but it's still just shy of 60 lines of uncommented code (I can add comments if you'd still like the code),  but I think all of that code is required to understand the function. Would you still like me to copy and paste ~46 lines of code?

Comment: Without it, it's impossible to say why it won't work as a function.

Comment: @JoeHabel You're right. The code has been added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to accomplish? I still do not understand. You have a whole chunck of code.  Try this out:

```
from sympy import *

def parse(expr): print(simplify(expr).evalf().nsimplify())

parse(-sqrt(-2.0 + 2*sqrt(3)*I))
-1 - sqrt(3)*I
```

Answer (score 0):

I think everything that you're fighting to do here can be made easier with what sympy has built in. First, assuming that you're taking in user given strings, I'd recommend using the built in parser's of sympy. Second, sympy will do this exact calculation for you, although with a caveat.

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

def simplify_string(polynomial_str):
    polynomial = parse_expr(polynomial_str)
    return polynomial.powsimp().evalf()
```

Usage examples:

```
>>>simplify_string('-sqrt(-2 + 2*sqrt(3)*I)')
-1.0 - 1.73205080756888*I
>>>simplify_string('sqrt(sqrt(1 + sqrt(2)*I) + I*sqrt(3 - I*sqrt(5)))')
1.54878147282944 + 0.78803305913*I
>>>simpify_string('sqrt((3 + sqrt(2 + sqrt(3)*I)*I)*x**2 + (3 + sqrt(5)*I)*x + I*4)'
(x**2*(3.0 + I*(2.0 + 1.73205080756888*I)**0.5) + x*(3.0 + 2.23606797749979*I) + 4.0*I)**0.5
```

The problem is, that sympy will either work in floats, or exact. If you want sympy to calculate out the numerical value of a square root, it's going to display what could be an int as a float for clarity. You can't fix the typecasting, but a lot of the work that you're trying to do, sympy has built in under the hood.

### Edit

You can use `.nsimplify()` on the polynomial to bring things back to nice looking numbers if possible, but you won't be able to have both evaluated roots, and nice displays in the same form.

Answer (score 0):

The `sqrtdenest` batteries are already included. If you replace ints expressed as floats it will work:

```
>>> from sympy import sqrtdenest, sqrt, Float
>>> eq = -sqrt(-2.0 + 2*sqrt(3)*I)
```

Define a function that will extract Floats that are equal to ints

```
>>> intfloats = lambda x: dict([(i,int(i)) for i in x.atoms(Float) if i==int(i)])
```

Use it to transform eq and then apply the `sqrtdenest`

```
>>> eq.xreplace(intfloats(eq))
-sqrt(-2 + 2*sqrt(3)*I)
>>> sqrtdenest(_)
-1 + sqrt(3)
```

A problem with using `nsimplify` (or any mass simplification) is that it may do more than you want. It's best to use the most specific transformation as possible to limit the impact (and work).

/!\ `sqrtdenest` appears to have a problem that I will report: it is dropping the `I`

Comment: `sqrtdenest` has now been fixed in the development version of SymPy.